# How to hide a CSS media query from print? "not" logical operator does not work

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to hide a media query from being printed, so I came up with `@media not print and (min-width:732px)`. But for whatever reason, this (and many variations I have tried) does not display as I would expect in browsers.

The only option I can think of is to use `@media screen and (max-width:732px)`, but I would like to avoid this as it excludes all the other media types besides screen.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly it does not display as you would expect?

Comment: We had a similar issue. Some browsers simply ignore the entire declaration if `not print` is there and therefore don't apply any of the styles inside the `max-width` media query.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Media queries grammar is pretty limited to say the least.

But with CSS3 (not CSS2.1) it seems that you can nest `@media` rules.

```
@media not print {
    @media (min-width:732px) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This basically executes as `(not print) and (min-width:732px)`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747166/3291457 for more info.

Answer (score 9):

How about something like this?

```
body { min-width:732px; }
@media print {
   body { min-width:initial; }
}
```

The min-width will be set to 732 for everything, except print, which will get some other value that you specify. Depending on your situation, you can set a different width, or try something like "thiswontwork" (which sometimes causes the value to be set to the initial value) or "inherit" or something like that.

Comment: I like your idea better than @turboki's because overriding is more future friendly than specifying every media type and hoping they don't add more.

Comment: `initial` has poorer support than media queries or the `print` media type, so on some browsers `min-width` may continue to be `732px` - be careful!

Answer (score 7):

If I'm correct in my assumptions about the behavior you expected, the issue is that [the precedence of `not` is lower than `and`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries#Operator_precedence).

`@media not print and (min-width:732px)` means "any media except for printers with at least 732px-wide viewports" (so it will apply to any non-printer and skinny printers) not "any media except printers, as long as that media has at least a 732px-wide viewport" (which is what I assume you expected).

Since parentheses aren't valid around media types and `@media` rules cannot be nested, working around it is kind of annoying. For simple cases, [brentonstrine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592198/3625) is a good solution, but for queries which enclose many styles it can be burdensome to make sure they're all overridden properly.

I put together some [example media queries](http://jsfiddle.net/qbdyj/) when I was trying to figure this out myself earlier today.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, you can fake nested media queries by using an `@import` with a media query or the `media` attribute on a `<link>` element and including the "child" `@media` rules (or additional `@import`s) in the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

As you can't put something like this

`@media screen,handheld,projection,tv,tty and (max-width:732px) { ... }`

you should write pairs for each media like following:

```
@media screen and (max-width:732px), handheld and (max-width:732px), projection and (max-width:732px), tv and (max-width:732px), tty and (max-width:732px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
@media screen,handheld,projection,tv,tty { ... }
```

Comment: That is a good idea. Any idea why the `not print` does not work?

Comment: I think it should work, except as per W3C spec: "User agents that only support media types (as described in HTML4) will not recognize the ‘not’ keyword and the associated style sheet is therefore not applied."

Answer (score 0):

The above nested query didn't work for me, but after a little reading on [Media Queries Media Types at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_types), you can exclude you're media query from print styles by specifying the `screen` type

So if you have a media query like this which doesn't specify a type, it will have an implied type of `all`, (which will affect print styles)

```
@media (min-width:400px) {
     ...
}
```

To exclude the style from print styles, you'd need to change it to this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:700px) {
      ...
}
```