# Nesting @media rules in CSS

Tags: css, media-queries

Support seems to be different across browsers..

Check the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uZnud/2/embedded/result/)

Firefox: Black with white text.

Opera, Chrome, IE9: Blue with black text.

Which is correct and how would I make it consistent?

The code

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

    body{
        background-color:#6aa6cc;
        color:#000;    
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

        body{
            background-color:#000;
            color:#fff;    
        }
    }
}
```

​

Interestingly enough it appears that nesting media queries within a conditional `@import` does seem to work.

e.g:

#### Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Media test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="importer.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Why is this not consistent.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

#### importer.css

```css
@import url(media.css) screen and (min-width: 480px);
```

#### media.css

```css
body {
    background-color: #6aa6cc;
    color: #000;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    body {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For those simply looking for an answer to "Which browsers support nesting of `@media` rules?", the short answer is that all modern browsers, including Firefox, Safari, Chrome (and its derivatives), and Microsoft Edge, now support nesting of `@media` at-rules as described in [CSS Conditional 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing). The code in the question with the nested `@media` at-rules should now work correctly everywhere, with the exception of Internet Explorer (which is [no longer being updated with new features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184048/what-is-after-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-7-how-well-will-es2016-be-support/35184087#35184087), meaning no version of IE will ever support this feature).

This feature did not exist in [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule), since only media types existed at the time which you could simply group with a comma, which explains why support for this was very poor at the time this question was first asked.

What follows is an analysis of the original question with these historical limitations in mind.

---

There's a bit of terminology confusion that needs clearing up in order for us to understand what exactly is happening.

The code you have refers to `@media` rules, and not so much media queries — the media query itself is the component that follows the `@media` token, whereas the rule is the entire block of code consisting of `@media`, the media query, and the rules nested within its set of curly braces.

This may cause confusion among many when it comes to using media queries in CSS, as well as your specific case where a `@media` rule in an imported stylesheet works correctly even when the `@import` is accompanied by another media query. Notice that media queries can occur in both `@media` and `@import` rules. They're the same thing, but they're being used to restrictively apply style rules in different ways.

Now, the actual issue here is that nested `@media` rules are [not valid in CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule) because you're not allowed to nest *any* at-rules within `@media` rules. However, things seem quite different in CSS3. Namely, the Conditional Rules module [states very clearly](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing) that `@media` rules *can* be nested, even providing an example:

> For example, with this set of nested rules:
>
> ```css
> @media print { /* rule (1) */
>   /* hide navigation controls when printing */
>   #navigation { display: none }
>   @media (max-width: 12cm) { /* rule (2) */
>     /* keep notes in flow when printing to narrow pages */
>     .note { float: none }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> the condition of the rule marked (1) is true for print media, and the condition of the rule marked (2) is true when the width of the display area (which for print media is the page box) is less than or equal to 12cm. Thus the rule ‘#navigation { display: none }’ applies whenever this style sheet is applied to print media, and the rule ‘.note { float: none }’ is applied only when the style sheet is applied to print media and the width of the page box is less than or equal to 12 centimeters.

Furthermore, it looks like Firefox is following this specification and processing the rules accordingly, whereas the other browsers are still treating it the CSS2.1 way.

The grammar in the [Syntax module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#detailed-grammar) hasn't been updated to reflect this yet, though; it still disallows nesting of at-rules within `@media` rules as with CSS2.1. This specification is slated for a rewrite anyway, so I guess this doesn't matter.

Basically, CSS3 allows it (pending rewriting the Syntax module), but not CSS2.1 (because it neither defines media queries nor allows nested `@media` rule blocks). And while at least one browser has begun supporting the new spec, I wouldn't call other browsers buggy; instead, I'll say that they simply haven't caught up yet as they're really conforming to an older, more stable spec.

Lastly, the reason why your `@import` works is because `@import` is able to work conditionally with the help of a media query. However this has no relation to the `@media` rule in your imported stylesheet. These are in fact two separate things, and are treated as such by all browsers.

To make your code work consistently across browsers, you can either use your `@import` statement, or, since both of your rules use `min-width`, simply remove the nesting of your `@media` rules:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: #6aa6cc;
        color: #000;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Interesting stuff. I added the @import example just to show that it works. I'm always amazed how this kind of stuff can be touted as supported by browsers but with vastly different behaviours.

Comment: @James South: Indeed. I've also added some explanation for your `@import` example. After rereading the spec I felt I needed to go over that for you.

Comment: Nice but CSS comments must use /* ... */ and not // ; // is used for comments in some sample CSS you supplied.

Comment: @Albert Wiersch: I didn't supply the CSS myself, that really is [what it originally looked like](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-conditional-20110901/#processing). You'd think the spec of all things would've gotten it right. But at least they fixed it now, after nearly a decade.