# Why don't CSS media queries follow the normal conventions of inheritance and cascade?

Tags: css, inheritance, media-queries, css-cascade

I've been having some issues with my CSS3 media queries...

Here's a small snippet of one I'm currently working on:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 420px) {
    .page { min-width: 300px; max-width: 480px; width: 100%; }
    .page .alpha { font-size: 2em; }

    /* Set-up the column */
    .page .column { margin: 0 auto 2%; width: auto; }
    .page .gallery .column { min-height: 470px; height: auto; padding: 2%; }
}

/* Increase the main title for slightly larger screens! */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 480px) {
    .page .alpha { font-size: 3em; }
}
```

I'm working from a 'mobile first' standpoint and given the normal behaviour of CSS regarding the 'cascading' aspect I would expect the second `@media` statement to inherit all of the styles from the previous statement, whilst overriding any for which it has a matching or 'heavier' selector.

(Plus CSS's order of precedence would mean any matching style definitions would use the last defined rule-set unless 'trumped' with an `!important` statement!)

From what I've seen though, through testing and some Google / SE searches this is not the case.

Is it possible for `@media` style rules to inherit from applicable earlier statements or am I stuck with having to repeat all the rules I need for each statement? (not very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

I'd really appreciate any help and clarifications / explanations for this.

Comment: fyi update -- I was wondering if nesting the second statement would work. It is in the CSS3 spec but some search results suggested that it's not supported in browsers yet?

Comment: That is quite correct - currently only Firefox supports it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css/11747166#11747166).

Comment: Note that CSS's definition of "inheritance" does not apply here since `@media` rules don't have any parent-child semantics whatsoever. This is purely a cascade issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly thanks @BoltClock (for both comments), and to the other comments and answers for all your help.

I think I made a mistake in my media queries and/or was miss-understanding how they worked and interacted together. I was going to edit my question with the following but decided it would make more sense as an answer (since it's the solution I used). I apologise if this has wasted anyone else's time.

Here's my *fixed* snippet of code:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 480px) {
    .page { min-width: 300px; max-width: 480px; width: 100%; }
    .page .alpha { font-size: 2em; }

    /* Set-up the column */
    .page .column { margin: 0 auto 2%; width: auto; }
    .page .gallery .column { min-height: 470px; height: auto; padding: 2%; }
}
/* Increase the main title for slightly larger screens! */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 421px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
    .page .alpha { font-size: 3em; }
}
```

I realised from your comments that if I increased the max-width in my first block to cover the necessary range/limit I could then either nest or add the second block after it (I tried both and they both worked for me -- using chromium browser [18.0.1025.151]). This successfully gave me the desired result, in that the `page .alpha` element's font size increased at the required stepping/interval.

Thanks again for all SO'ers who helped!
(and to SE for the awesome communities they've helped build)

*Knowledge > OpenSource > Freedom*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work from mobile up, you will need to set the mobile layout as the default layout. (Remove the query). From there the queries will inherit from above.

```
.page { min-width: 300px; max-width: 480px; width: 100%; }
.page .alpha { font-size: 2em; }

 /* Set-up the column */
.page .column { margin: 0 auto 2%; width: auto; }
.page .gallery .column { min-height: 470px; height: auto; padding: 2%; }

/* Increase the main title for slightly larger screens! */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 480px) {
    .page .alpha { font-size: 3em; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your mobile first tip -- I have some base styles outside of my MQ's but it makes more sense to have the smallest mobile ones here too! Although this still doesn't explain why @media rules don't cascade the way other css rules do.

Comment: @Chris: As far as I can tell, the `@media (max-width : 420px)` rules should stop applying only when the width exceeds 420px. If you're not seeing those rules taking effect *at all*, something is wrong. Other than that, `@media` rules are supposed to follow the same cascade as all other rules do.