# Media query works on mobile Firefox but doesn't work on mobile Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm facing the problem with media queries on mobile devices.
I've got something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px){
/* Some styles*/
}
```

I'm testing my website on Galaxy S6. In Firefox everything looks fine and styles do change but when i load the same website in Chrome - there's no change and it looks like the media query doesn't work.
Does Chrome need some special queries?

Comment: Why are you using `min-/max-device-width` instead of `min-/max-width`?

Comment: '@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 1000px)' doesn't work either on Chrome

Comment: Did you declare your viewport in the HTML meta? This has led to problems for me before. Media queries simply didn't kick in.

Comment: Thanks @Falk ! This code done the trick and now everything works fine ;)

Comment: Let me supply it as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this meta tag into the header of your HTML file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This should solve your problem. Otherwise the browser might not resize because it will not accept that the screen size is meeting your media query criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and I thought it was related to [`@media` queries nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095429/6225838) (that only Firefox currently implements). Since it was a foreign huge CSS file I was dealing with, I wasted a lot of time separating each and every rule into more restrictive queries (ranges with min, max, pixel-ratio and resolution)...

Later I found that after this line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

In another template there was another line with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=639, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

This was overriding the first rule and, with the exception of Firefox (mobile), it actually created a couple of problems:

- all the media queries that had `max-width` under `639px` were being ignored in Chrome (or the default Android browser);
- queries with `max-device-width` syntax were also being ignored (only `max-width` ones worked).

So my suggestion is, before you head on checking all the problems in the CSS, have a look first at all the meta tags that may be affecting the viewport.