# Check if SASS parent selector exists. Is it possible

Tags: sass

I have a question. So in a mixing I am making a reference to the parent selector "&". This works as long as the mixin is not nested. Is there a way to to detect if the mixing is being used in a non nested scenario, or to check if "&" is null?

This works when the mixin call is not nested

```
=myresponsiveMixin($media)
  @if $media == small {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $break-small)
       @content
  @else if $media == medium
    @media only screen and (min-width: $break-small + 1) and (max-width: $break-large - 1)
       @content
```

This works great when the mixin call is nested, but will not resolve '&' when not nested

```
 =myresponsiveMixin($media)
      @if $media == small {
        @media only screen and (max-width: $break-small)
           .classInHTMLToAllowMediaQueries &
               @content
      @else if $media == medium
        @media only screen and (min-width: $break-small + 1) and (max-width: $break-large - 1)
           .classInHTMLToAllowMediaQueries &
               @content
```

So the question is, if there is a way to be able to check the value of parent selector "&", so I can cover all bases in a single mixin?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? You may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to be able to use a mixin with a parent class.For example
<code>
    =responsiveMixin
        .responsive &
            Do responsive stuff
</code>

a mixin like the above will work as long as the mixing is called while nested. But I want it to be usable even when not nested. For example.

Comment: Please edit your initial question and provide the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
@mixin does-parent-exist {
  @if & {
    .exists & {
      color: red;
    }
  } @else {
    .doesnt-exist {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-script

Answer (score 0):

You're trying a wrong solution to solve your issue.

Have a look at how this problem is addressed in powerful SASS frameworks. Let's take [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) by [Eric Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930386/eric-meyer) as a great example.

Let's imagine you've got the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Bla bla
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you call a mixin for the first time, you're doing it simply (the code is in the indented .sass syntax):

```
$total-columns: 8 // Declaring a varible that will be used by the mixin

.parent
  +span-columns(4) // Span four of eight columns
```

But when you call that for a child element, the proportions would be crooked, because the parent is already proportioned:

```
.child
  +span-columns(2) // This will fail. You want 2 of 8 columns,
                   // but due to nesting the math is crooked.
                   // It will be "2 of (4 of 8)".
```

To address the issue, you provide an optional argument: a context that is used to do the math:

```
.child
  +span-columns(2, 4) // Now the mixin will take 2 parts of 4
                      // instead of 2 parts of four
```

The source code for this mixin is [available](https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/master/sass/susy/_grid.scss) on GitHub.

In short, it creates an optional argument like this (the code is in the CSS-like .scss syntax):

```
@mixin span-columns(
  $columns,
  $context: $total-columns
  //...
) {
  //...
  width: columns($cols, $context /*...*/);
  //...
}
```

See how `$context` has a default value? Thanks to the default value this argument can be omitted. In other words, `$context` is an optional argument.

When calling this mixin, if `$context` is not provided (e. g. `span-columns(2)`), then it is set equal to `$total-columns`. The `$total-columns` variable should be set prior to calling the mixin for the first time (see my example above).

Then the two arguments are used to calculate the width.

### UPD 2013-03-30

> I am not trying to figure out things in regards to columns... I have modifier my question to make it clearer.

**First of all**, my recommendation concerns not only grid columns. It's a universal technique you can adopt.

**Secondly**, now i see that you're trying to nest media queries.

Well, *some* media queries of different type can be combined in CSS3: e. g. `print` and width. But you can't put a `min-width: 601px` inside `max-width: 600px`, this just won't work!

There's an extensive answer here on StackOverflow describing why you should not nest media queries of the same type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747166/901944

**Thirdly**, you're trying to invent the wheel. There's already a fantastic mixin for crunching media queries: [Respond To](https://github.com/snugug/respond-to) by [Snugug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703084/snugug). It's super easy to use and very effective.

**Fourthly**, the [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) thing. Instead of asking about your crooked mixin, please describe the problem that you're trying to solve with it! Show us the actual HTML and explain what behavior you would like to achieve.

We will show you that it can be solved with a simple, elegant, semantic solution that does not require SASS hacking.

Comment: I am not trying to figure out things in regards to columns... I have modifier my question to make it clearer.

Comment: The media mixin I have above is exactly the same as respond to. Its just in scss format. But that being the case neither of the two solve the issue i have.  
If you read the media query above the output is the same, and there is no nesting of media queries. The output is exactly the same as that of respond to, as its the same thing in SASS syntax.  Now the second media query allows me to ignore the media queries when the class `. classInHTMLToAllowMediaQueries` is not available to boot.  Allows me to disable responsive in some sections. The problem is it uses parent selector.

Comment: Oh, now i understand you. Please tell me why are you using a class to enable media queries?

Comment: Gonna weigh in here, because I'm encountering a similar problem: I believe that `.classInHTMLToAllowMediaQueries` is actually a class that gets added on (via JavaScript, UA sniffing (evil), or IE conditional comments) when media queries aren't supported. So IE8 might get the desktop version.

Comment: Then it would be a class to enable a mediaquery-less design.