# In SASS, is there a way to declare refer to the subclass of the block's parent?

Tags: sass

I am looking for a way to refer to a certain subclass of the parent of the block i am currently writing declarations in.

Let me illustrate.

**Instead of:**

```
.label {
    @extend .not-selectable;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```

**And then:**

```
&.active .label {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

**I'd like to write something like:**

```
.label {
    @extend .not-selectable;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 22px;
    << &.active {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
}
```

With the resulting, compiled CSS being exactly the same in both cases.

Is there any such syntax or hack or trick in SASS to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668539/check-if-sass-parent-selector-exists-is-it-possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668539/check-if-sass-parent-selector-exists-is-it-possible).