# Does IE11 auto update to Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I am wondering about future browser support...

Will IE11 auto update to Microsoft Edge, or will we be stuck with a huge chunk of IE11 users in the future (much like IE6)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge are two separate browsers.

Microsoft Edge is prominently featured on the Start screen and app list on Windows 10, so most consumers will discover Microsoft Edge and be "upgraded" to it in that sense when they upgrade to Windows 10 or buy a new device with Windows 10 preinstalled. IE11 remains available for enterprise users and consumers who need compatibility with legacy sites and technologies like ActiveX, but [it won't be updated with any new web platform features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184048/what-is-after-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-7-how-well-will-es2016-be-support/35184087#35184087).

You only really have to support IE11 if a significant portion of your userbase consists of Windows 7 and 8.1 users (as Microsoft Edge is only available on Windows 10), or if you are maintaining a site that was built using older technologies.

See the [FAQ](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq) for more details.

Comment: It's worth noting that [Windows 10 is offered as a free upgrade to Windows 7 and 8.1 users](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade) as well, so more and more people will be migrating from IE 11 to Microsoft Edge.