# CSS/SCSS Adjacent sibling selector between certain types

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Is there any way to accomplish all combinations of sibling selectors without having to write them all one by one?

Let's say I want `font-size: 30px;` in the second element, and any element can be an `a`, `b` or `span`.

I would normally write:

```
a + b, b + a, a + span, span + a, b + span, span + b {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

But that's leads to `n*(n-1)` combinations!

I'm looking forward something like this:

```
{a,b,span} + {a,b,span} {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Though if there is no alternatively let me know if the best choice is to always make sure that the elements contained are always the types I want so I can use *:

```
* + * {...}
```

CSS solution if possible, or SCSS if it leads to a cleaner or the only unique possible solution.

**Edit:**

Some of you are suggesting `nth-child`. Whilst this is good for one or two formattings, that was not my aim (my fault, should've probably specified it better).

I meant to give result to a long div of text containing different formatting. I.e.:

```
<div class="text">
  <span>The weather</span> <i>is</is> <img src... /> <b>nice</b> <span>today</span>
</div>
```

So, what I thought at first was to change the ones I wanted to format to `<div class="whatever">` so I could just focus `div` with certain class. But then again, something like `{ span, i, b }` would be the most ideal.

Comment: What about this ? https://jsfiddle.net/0zguo1jr/1/

Comment: @VincentG That's not the ideal solution, I would always have to make sure that the element next to `a` is the type I want to format.

Comment: You could use `* > :nth-child(2)` or `:nth-child(2)`, but that would lead to an inheritance/cascade nigthtmare' unless you really do want every second child (without limitation) to be styled.

Comment: @DavidThomas Ugh yeah :/, I'd rather make sure that all elements are of the correct type than having to hard-code every `nth-child`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In compliant browsers (*sigh...*), there's the option of using:

```
:matches(a, b, span) + :matches(a, b, span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

To style the `:nth-child(2)` element that is an `<a>`, `<b>` or `<span>` element following a previous sibling element of the type `<a>`, `<b>` or `<span>`.

The problem, of course, is that "*in compliant browsers*" part, and so far IE and Edge are both reluctant to join that particular party. Also, Webkit (Chrome, Opera and Android) are implementing a vendor-prefixed incorrect version using `:-webkit-any()`. On the plus side, though, as I write now, Safari, both desktop and iOS implement the `:matches()` pseudo-class correctly.

So, if you don't require IE/Edge support you have the option of:

```
:-webkit-any(a, b, span) + :-webkit-any(a, b, span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
:-moz-any(a, b, span) + :-moz-any(a, b, span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
:matches(a, b, span) + :matches(a, b, span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```css
a::before {
  content: 'link';
}
b::before {
  content: 'bold'
}
span::before {
  content: 'span';
}
em::before {
  content: 'em';
}
:-webkit-any(a,
b,
span) +:-webkit-any(a,
b,
span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
:-moz-any(a,
b,
span) +:-moz-any(a,
b,
span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
:matches(a,
b,
span) +:matches(a,
b,
span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"></a> <span></span>
</div>
<div><span></span>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div><b></b>  <span></span>
</div>
<div><b></b>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div><b></b>  <em></em>
</div>
<div><em></em>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gL7u5d5c/).

References:

- [`:any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any).
- [`:matches()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches-pseudo).
- [Compatibility for `:matches()`](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Amatches).

Comment: `any` and `matches` is definitely what I was looking for

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help! Although I'm a little disappointed that - after a half hour of looking - I *still* can't work out how to achieve the same in SCSS/SASS (although in my defence I've never used it before...).

Comment: Considering that CSS works with SCSS, I'm good with that. Thanks once again :)

Comment: The pseudo-class was originally implemented by Moz as :-moz-any() for internal use years before being proposed and specced as :matches(). Calling it "incorrect" is disingenuous at best. Also, it's 2017, but I don't think any vendors other than Apple have planned to implement all or most of selectors-4 just yet. Who knows how long that'll take.

Comment: Additionally, [IE is no longer being actively developed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184048/what-is-after-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-7-how-well-will-es2016-be-support/35184087#35184087). Only Microsoft Edge will be receiving new features down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
a *:nth-child(2), b *:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

should work

Comment: Did you mean to write what @DavidThomas has just commented? If that's the case, my answer still remains the same. I'd rather make sure that all elements are of the correct type than having to hard-code every `nth-child`.