# How can SASS be used to emulate the use of :matches(a, b) + :matches(a, b):nth-child(2)?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

In answering the question "[CSS/SCSS Adjacent sibling selector between certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425284/css-scss-adjacent-sibling-selector-between-certain-types/41425735#41425735)," in which the OP wanted to have the second-child of a parent-element styled if it, and the preceding sibling, was an element of various types.

I proposed an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425735/82548) using the `matches()` selector (albeit both Firefox and Webkit browsers are – at the time of writing – using vendor-prefixed implementations of the `:any()` pseudo-class).

Somewhat as a tradition of times gone by both Internet Explorer and Edge fail to implement any version of the selector, either `:any()` or `:matches()`, although since it's an experimental feature I can't attach blame for that decision or 'failure.'

However, for compatibility's sake I'd like to ask: is there a means by which SASS might be used to form the appropriate selectors to reliably style the following:

```css
a::before {
  content: 'link';
}
span::before {
  content: 'span';
}
b::before {
  content: 'b';
}
em::before {
  content: 'em';
}
:-webkit-any(a, b, span) + :-webkit-any(a, b, span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
:-moz-any(a, b, span) + :-moz-any(a, b, span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
:matches(a, b, span) + :matches(a, b, span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>The second element child of each of these following &lt;div&gt; elements should be styled</h2>
  <div>
    <span></span>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>The second element child of each of these following &lt;div&gt; elements should <em>not</em> be styled</h2>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <em></em>
  </div>
  <div>
    <em></em>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

With SASS I'd expect, or at least *imagine*, that the groupings should be expanded from the following form (though I'm unsure, hence this question, as to *how* to emulate the `:matches()` syntax or what the SASS syntax might be):

```
:matches(a, b, span) + :matches(a, b, span):nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

Into an explicit selector, such as:

```
a + a:nth-child(2),
a + b:nth-child(2),
a + span:nth-child(2),
b + a:nth-child(2),
b + b:nth-child(2),
b + span:nth-child(2),
span + a:nth-child(2),
span + b:nth-child(2),
span + span:nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```css
a::before {
  content: 'link';
}
span::before {
  content: 'span';
}
b::before {
  content: 'b';
}
em::before {
  content: 'em';
}
a + a:nth-child(2),
a + b:nth-child(2),
a + span:nth-child(2),
b + a:nth-child(2),
b + b:nth-child(2),
b + span:nth-child(2),
span + a:nth-child(2),
span + b:nth-child(2),
span + span:nth-child(2) {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>The second element child of each of these following &lt;div&gt; elements should be styled</h2>
  <div>
    <span></span>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>The second element child of each of these following &lt;div&gt; elements should <em>not</em> be styled</h2>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <em></em>
  </div>
  <div>
    <em></em>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`:any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any).
- [`:matches()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches-pseudo).
- [Compatibility for `:matches()`](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Amatches).

Comment: Scratch that, I misunderstood your question lol.

Comment: I had wondered if I'd phrased it really badly... Although I do understand your initial (now deleted) point: it does seem a little backward. But, as I think you've realised, it's less less about using a preprocessor to emulate a selector which itself was designed/created to avoid preprocessors, but instead to recreate the convenience of `:matches()` in browsers that don't yet understand that selector. :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution, not as concise as using `:matches`, but near enough:

```
a, b, span {
    & + a, & + b, & + span {
        &:nth-child(2) {
            color: #f90;
        }
   }
}
```

Another one would be to explicitly do the expanding loops:

```
$tags: a, b, span;
@each $a in $tags {
   @each $b in $tags {
        #{$a} + #{$b}:nth-child(2) {
            color: #f90;
        }
   }
}
```

(which could also be written using a mixin, but that wouldn't make it look much better...)

But really at this point I would work upstream to ensure there's a class instead of those 3 tags.

Comment: While that works I must admit that I was hoping for something that didn't involve the `& + a, & + b, & + span` stage; although I do love the brevity of the final brace.

Comment: I'm looking for a better solution... But you know just like me that any sane developer would use classes to avoid that type of mess...

Comment: I'm with you on that, yes; although for the purposes of this question I'm more curious about the syntax problem - since I've looked at the SASS documentation but never used it, and it feels like a problem that wasn't quite solved and an answer I'd like to see :)

Comment: That looks...well '*beautiful*' isn't the word, certainly, but it looks convincingly like the solution I'm looking for. I'll give it a while before I accept an answer, though, if only to see what (potential, hypothetical) other answers might be.

Comment: I didn't look at the source code of sass but if I seriously had this problem I would consider doing a PR to just implement `:matches` directly into sass.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work, considering Sass and other preprocessors compile directly into CSS, in which the :matches() pseudo is already defined and implemented natively in at least one browser.

Comment: @BoltClock We could use an alternate syntax, I guess. And the point would only be to expand for those browsers which don't understand the standard operator. (edited)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `postcss` with the `level4` plugin. This will transform `:matches` to their equivalent CSS3 queries.

```
li:matches(:last-child, .fancy) { ... }

/* compiles to */

li:last-child, li.fancy { ... }
```

Documentation and examples (such as the above) can be found on the Github page of level4: https://github.com/stephenway/level4.

Comment: I like how that project lists custom properties and custom selectors as "level 4" features. (I get custom media queries because they *were* part of MQ L4 before being punted to L5 sometime last year, long after the project was last updated.)