# Is it possible to combine translateX/translateY and scale in single CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, transition

I have been playing around with looping of CSS transitions (following [this article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/looping_a_css_transition.htm)).

The transition itself could be divided into 4 (looped) phases:
*shrinked2=>expanded=>expanded2=>shrinked*
These states are represented by 4 classes:
*shrinked2* - `stateOne` 
*expanded* - `stateTwo` 
*expanded2* - `stateThree` 
*shrinked2* - `stateFour` 

I am, initially, setting the width and height of my element, being transitioned, in percents via id. Then, to trigger transition, I am changing `transform: scale` via state classes, listed above.

Up to his point it basically works fine for me, here is [demonstration on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/1cf98h76/).

Now, as the next step I would like to center the transitioned element, vertically and horizontally, on the page (and keep it there). I am doing so by adding the following, to the element id:

`top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);`

as well as appending each `transform:`, in the state classes, with `translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)`. Now this way the `scale` is not applied to the element (i.e. size is not changed on transition) - only `background` property is affected, transition only happens once (i.e. it is not looped anymore), as if `transitionend` was never fired.
Here is [the result on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/1cf98h76/1/). Changing of expected property name (in `loopTransition` function) to `background`, [has not effect (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/1cf98h76/2/).

I am totally aware that there are [lots](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564) ways to center the element. What I would like to understand is:

1. Is it possible to combine  `translateX`/`translateY` and `scale` in the same CSS transition (if yes, what am I doing wrong?)
2. If element centering with `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` is not compatible with transitions in general or `scale` in particular, what is the recommended method to use?

```js
var the_circle = document.getElementById('circle');
the_circle.addEventListener("transitionend", loopTransition);

function startTransition() {
    var the_circle = document.getElementById('circle');
    if (the_circle.className === 'stateOne paused') {
        the_circle.style.transitionDuration = 1;
        the_circle.className = 'stateTwo animated';
    } else {
        stopTransition();
    }
}

function stopTransition() {
    var the_circle = document.getElementById('circle');
    the_circle.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s"
    the_circle.className = "stateOne paused"
}

function loopTransition(e) {
    var the_circle = document.getElementById('circle');
    if (e.propertyName === "transform") {
        if (the_circle.className.indexOf('paused') !== -1) {
            stopTransition()
        } else {
            if (the_circle.className === "stateTwo animated") {
                the_circle.style.transitionDuration = "1s";
                the_circle.className = "stateThree animated";
            } else if (the_circle.className === "stateThree animated") {
                the_circle.style.transitionDuration = "1s";
                the_circle.className = "stateFour animated";
            } else if (the_circle.className === "stateFour animated") {
                the_circle.style.transitionDuration = "1s";
                the_circle.className = "stateOne animated";
            } else if (the_circle.className === "stateOne animated") {
                the_circle.style.transitionDuration = "1s";
                the_circle.className = "stateTwo animated";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#circle {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.stateOne {
    background: #800080;
    transform: scale(1.0001, 1.0001) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.stateTwo {
    background: #ffe6ff;
    transform: scale(2, 2) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.stateThree {
    background: #ffe6ff;
    transform: scale(2.0001, 2.0001) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.stateFour {
    background: #800080;
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='circle' class="stateOne paused" onclick=startTransition()></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with [`animation` & `keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)?

Comment: @Svenskunganka Yes I have, (see: [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46402020/8554766) and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/rpve2e9L/)), and it's working perfectly fine. Though, as I am doing this stuff for studying purposes, my goal is to make it work with `transition` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In CSS, `#id` selectors take precedence over `.class` selectors. Therefore, the `transform` declarations in your `.state` classes never get applied. The solution is to either:

   - increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your rule, i.e. `#circle.stateTwo`,
   - add the `!important` flag to your declaration:

     ```
     transform: scale(2, 2) translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
     ```

     However this should be avoided and the first method used whenever possible.
2. An easier method to center elements, that doesn't mix with your animation, is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

   ```
   .flex-container {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
   }

   #circle {
     width: 10%;
     padding-top: 10%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     transition: all 1s;
   }

   .stateOne {
     background: #800080;
     transform: scale(1.0001, 1.0001);
   }

   .stateTwo {
     background: #ffe6ff;
     transform: scale(2, 2);
   }

   .stateThree {
     background: #ffe6ff;
     transform: scale(2.0001, 2.0001);
   }

   .stateFour {
     background: #800080;
     transform: scale(1, 1);
   }
   ```

Comment: I assume that `left` and `right` positioning by percentage does not take into account the `scale` transform, yet translate does. I might test this later on...

Comment: The first suggested method (using `#circle.stateTwo`) centers the element initially, though [fails (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/1cf98h76/3/) to keep it centered during transition, I'd appreciate and explanation on why this is happening. The second, method (using `flexbox`) [works (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/1cf98h76/4/) as intended, so I think I will stick with it. In any case, thanks for the answer!