# CSS to make a text field look like password field

Tags: html, css

How can I set the CSS for an input field of type `text` in html to appear as a password field, i.e. the text in the input seems to get replaced with a symbol such as the asterisk ("*") or a dot ("•")?

I have this constraint:

```html
<input name="passwordish" type="text" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" >
```

EDIT: Sorry if this was not clear, but for some snowflakish reasons I can't change the field type!

Comment: set type to password

Comment: check this out [link](https://codeburst.io/how-to-display-password-in-a-form-input-9381310c88c6)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I was there. I don't think it answers my question. I can't change the filed type in my HTML

Comment: @DaveIdito, works even without changing the field type. Check in fiddle.

Comment: @Code_Ninja but the Javascript there toggles the type: `document.getElementById('password');
  if (password.type === 'password') {
    password.type = 'text';
  } else {
    password.type = 'password';
  }
};` which is something I've to avoid.

Comment: If this toggles the type of the field. The code is still good to go as the CSS will be applied when the type is text. Otherwise, the text is already hidden. So, I dont think that any point of time, any user would be able to see the password. Unless they type `$("#inputPassword").val()` in the console. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3onwLev4/) is the fiddle. Check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

**Recommended** that you change text type to password

`<input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" >`

**OR this**

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/password-input-bullet-alternatives/)

```
input { -webkit-text-security: none; }
input { -webkit-text-security: circle; }
input { -webkit-text-security: square; }
input { -webkit-text-security: disc; /* Default */ }
```

**Update:**

[Mozilla/FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security)
 [Explination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53080353/6651840)

**Try this:**

```css
input {
    text-security: circle; /* IE/Safari */
    -moz-text-security: circle; /* FireFox */
    -webkit-text-security: circle; /* Chrome/Safari  */
}
```

**Update:**

- Firefox no more supports the following css:

  - `-webkit-text-security`
  - `-moz-text-security`

Tested on Firefox 69.0, Windows 10, 64bit,

Comment: CSS method doesn't work without changing the field type. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just checked in Fiddle, works fine with the HTML given in the question. Cool trick!

Comment: `-webkit-text-security` is an invalid proporty on Firefox 67.0.4

Comment: @DaveIdito `-webkit-text-security` is for chrome, brave and  afew other web browsers.

Comment: any css that starts with `-` followed by `webkit`, `moz` or others are browser specific css implementations.

Comment: according to the docs at moz website, it seems that its no more supported... [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

```
actualText = "";
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var tempText = x.replace(/\*/g,"");
  if(tempText == "")
  {
    actualText = actualText.substr(0, actualText.length - 1);
  }
  else {
    actualText += x.replace(/\*/g,"");
  }
  document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
  for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
    document.getElementById("myText").value += "*";
  }
}
```

Only problem is that you will not be able to use the actuall text.

Update:Added a variable that will store the text too. Use variable ***actualText*** to access original text ;)
Also about calling this function: you will have to call this function in ***onkeyup*** event of *input*

Comment: Then in that case, the code should be copied to another variable/div/hidden input field. Otherwise the above code would not be worth it at all.

Comment: Does this take backspace into account? I don't think so

Comment: @Daveldito yeah it didn't took backspace into account, check updated answer now, Thanks. And sorry for missing this out.