# What's the maximum nesting depth possible for a CSS rule?

Tags: css, syntax

In stylesheets, the majority of CSS rules (NOT talking about SASS or LESS here) are structured like this:

```
selector {
    property_1 : value_1;
    .
    .
    .
    property_n : value_n;
}
```

There is only 1 {} block attached to the selector (with no sub {} blocks inside). Call this **degree of nesting = 1**.

With at-rules though, we see rules such as this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {

    body {
        font-size: 20px;  
    }

}
```

There is clearly a nested CSS block inside the @media rule, so **degree of nesting = 2**

The highest I can imagine is something that has a **nesting degree = 3** such as this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
    
    @keyframes myidentifier {

        0%   { top: 0; left: 0; }
        100% { top: 100px; left: 100%; }

    }

}
```

Is it possible to nest CSS blocks any deeper than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional CSS Rules can be nested as deeply as you desire:

```
@media print {
  @media (max-width: 12cm) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem. I would recommend reading the W3 docs on [Conditional Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-media) if you want to learn more.

Comment: I'm glad this can be freely relied on today. At the time this was posted, I believe implementations were still slowly creeping in. Also check out (specifically for at-media rules) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css/11747166#11747166

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jeff's answer:

Style rules (previously called rulesets) — that is, rules with selectors and property-value declarations — cannot be nested in standard CSS. There is a proposed specification called [css-nesting](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting) that aims to bring this ability from popular stylesheet preprocessors to standard CSS, but it's not yet set in stone.

Conditional at-rules, such as `@media` and `@supports`, may be nested within one another as much as you like. You can even [nest one within the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438009/nesting-css-supports-and-media-queries). Previously, in CSS2.1, `@media` at-rules could not be nested, but this restriction has been removed in css-conditional-3, which contains a [section explaining how nesting of conditional rules works](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-conditional-3/#processing).

This does not apply to *all* at-rules that have a block, though. For example, [`@keyframes` at-rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/#keyframes) aren't conditional rules; these may appear within `@media` or `@supports` rules to any nesting depth, but cannot themselves *contain* conditional rules, or indeed other `@keyframes` rules. They may only contain keyframe blocks, such as the 0% and 100% blocks in your example.

As more modules are added to CSS, new at-rules may be added that have their own nesting restrictions defined in their respective specifications. However, anything defined in css-conditional-3 can be nested interchangeably and to any depth.