# Nesting CSS @supports and @media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, feature-detection

I have been trying to figure out whether it's possible to nest CSS feature queries (also known as “CSS `@supports`”) and regular media queries, and what would be the correct way to do it.

**Example A** shows the *feature query* inside the *media query.*
**Example B** shows the *media query* inside the *feature query.*

Is it even possible to nest them at all? If so, is there a preferred nesting style? A or B?

```
.foo {
    background: red;
}

/* EXAMPLE A */
@media (min-width: 50em) {
    .foo {
        background: green;
    }

    @supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
        .foo {
            background: blue;
        }
    }
}

/* EXAMPLE B */
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
    .foo {
        background: green;
    }

    @media (min-width: 50em) {
        .foo {
            background: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nesting media queries seems to be allowerd in css3. So I assume, feature queries may work as well. But getting cross browser compatiblity is another story.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you! At least I know now that we'll possibly get this in the future. I guess I'm back to testing browser support like it's 1999.

Comment: Scratch that, browser support seems to be just fine if you're only interested in browsers that support @supports. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Both examples are valid CSS according to [section 3 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#contents-of), and for the time being they seem to be consistently supported by browsers that understand both `@supports` rules and nested `@media` rules ([also new to CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css/11747166#11747166)).

Although both examples will only apply the `background: blue` declaration when *both* the `@media` and `@supports` conditions are met,

- A will apply either `background: green` or `background: blue` if and only if the `(min-width: 50em)` media query is met;
- B will apply either declaration if and only if the browser understands `@supports` and supports `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Since your two examples mean subtly different things, which one you choose will depend on your use case:

- If you do not want browsers that don't support `@supports` or `flex-wrap: wrap` to see *either* declaration, and to instead always apply `background: red`, choose B.
- Otherwise, if you want any browser (that understands media queries anyway) to apply `background: green` at the specified viewport width, even if it will never apply `background: blue` due to not supporting `@supports` or `flex-wrap: wrap`, choose A.

Comment: Dreamweaver validates only supports inside media, but not media inside supports, but its validator is not always good.