# Any side-effect problems may arise when using @media to group/create code-folding for css entries?

Tags: css, code-folding

In CSS 3 syntax we have @media to define responsive screen to apply.

I intend to use it as custom code-folding for CSS entries.

E.g.

```
@media {
    div { color: green; }
}
```

So I wonder if there are any side-effect problems may arise when doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the `@media` CSS at-rule is not new to CSS3. It was introduced in CSS2, and has been supported by every browser including IE5+. What *is* new to CSS3 are media *queries*. The difference between media queries and `@media` are detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css/11747166#11747166).

An `@media` rule without an accompanying media query is [equivalent to `@media all`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0), which, again, is understood correctly by every browser including IE5 and up. In other words, in terms of browser behavior there are no side-effects other than hiding CSS from IE4 and any other browsers from the late 90s (which don't support `@media` in any way, shape or form).

Note that this construct does not validate as either CSS2 or CSS3 in the [Jigsaw CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator); this is a bug with the validator which may be due to the fact that CSS2 did not explicitly allow empty media types with `@media`. Having said that, what *is* stated in CSS3 is consistent with browser behavior up to 17 years back, so this is something you can totally rely on.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation