# Styling for IE 11 using media queries not working correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

The issue I am having is that, in the following code, I am having to use an "!important" tag on a section of my styling, and on resizing I need to change this, I have nested my media query, but I cannot get it to receive the special instructions at the nested settings.

```
 @@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    #explorerStyle {
        width: 100%;
        left: -10px;
        margin-top: 36px !important;
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    @@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
        #explorerStyleSpan {
            margin-top: 16px !important; <<<<<< Issue is here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to find great cross-browser support for nesting media queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css/11747166#answer-11747166

Comment: @tsg Thank you very much for the response. I think I found a work around by adjusting the exterior element to fit what I needed to do.