# Hide text on page but show it on window.print

Tags: css

Anyone have idea how can I hide text, date or something on page, but when I click button for `window.print()` show it there? 
I'm using:

```css
@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 1.6cm; }
}

@media print {
  .hide-from-printer{  display:none; }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="window.print()" class="btn btn-success hide-from-printer">Print</a>
```

So like this button `class="hide-from-printer"`, it shows on page but hide from printing page. I want to do vice versa (on the contrary). Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a CSS media query from print? "not" logical operator does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591273/how-to-hide-a-css-media-query-from-print-not-logical-operator-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ´screen´ for regular screens so all you would have to do is

```
@media screen {
    .hide-from-screen {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media print {
     .hide-from-printer {
          display: none;
      }
 }
```

and use those classes accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Use this way:

```
.hide-from-page { display:none; } /* hide at normal page view */

@media print {
  .hide-from-page { display:inline; } /* make it visible during print */
}
```

Note: its obvious to rename the class to mean correctly (instead of `hide-from-printer`, it must be something like as `hide-from-page` or `show-only-at-print`)